# Laravel+TailwindCSS project shows perfectly on local machine. but CSS isn't working on mobile

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, tailwind-css, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I'm using laravel for a project (I'm somewhat new), for the front end I am using tailwindcss and vueJS. So my login page shows perfectly on host device (my pc). But when I access the page with my phone the css doesn't seem to work. I'm using `php artisan serve --host 192.168.31.121` (my pc's ip) to host and it also requires `npm run dev` for tailwind. The head part of my `login.blade.php` looks like this ->

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Laravel</title>
    @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss'])
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css'])
    @vite(['resources/js/app.js'])

</head>
```

I'm specially confused cause it works on the pc but not on my mobile.

I tried moving my css file to public from resources and tried this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
```

But it still didn't work.

Comment: `npm run dev` runs an asset/vite server on a different port that may not be reachable. Try running `npm run build` to actually build your assets to a public folder

Comment: After `npm run build` I got bunch of new files in the public>build>assets> where, on of the file was "app-ecd70a91.css"

If I use <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/assets/app-ecd70a91.css') }}"> on the login page, it seems to work.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to fix both of the problem. But Still unaware if that is the correct way to do things. 